# google maps route in ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I need to get a route between 2 location in asp, since I want variables to improve my page navigation. I found an excellent method online that works wonders, but it activates a onclick function to work. I need to reload the page to obtain variables from my database.

The original version is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var source, destination;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
    });

    function GetRoute() {
        var rome = new google.maps.LatLng(41.918357, 12.485029);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: rome
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

        //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
        source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
        destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

        var request = {
            origin: source,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });

        //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "<strong>" + "Distanza:" + "</strong>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + distance + "<br />";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "<strong>" + "Durata:" + "</strong>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + duration;

            } else {
                alert("Impossibile trovare la distanza stradale");
            }
});
    }
</script>
```

it's activated by a onclick="GetRoute()" command in the request form, where I input my departure and destination in two fields. It will then display a map with the two locations with the route informations by its side. 
Now, what I want, is to activate it with asp, since I need to access my sql.So the button type will become a submit without the onclick instruction, the page will reload, I'll get the data I need questioning my database and the gmaps script will run as usual, automatically triggering that GetRoute() function. I hope I've been clear, my english is a bit rusty, I could provide the work in progress address where I'm trying to fix this bad boy.

I'd like the whole script to be activated automatically after the page is reloaded, without the onclick command. So, basically, I want to get rid of the GetRoute() command. As long as I have the data needed by the script (txtSource and txtDestination), is there a way to obtain my map and route, once the page has reloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a slight modification to your existing code, 
using the `GetRoute` function, without the `onclick`:

In the GetRoute function, set the `source` and `destination` variables to the request values:

```
    function GetRoute() 
    {

        source = "<%=Request("txtSource")%>"; 
        destination = "<%=Request("txtDestination")%>"; 


        if( source != "" && destination != "")
        {

            /*the rest of your code as is,except the following change:
            comment out the following two lines, as we are already setting this with the request values
            source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
            destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;
            */


        }
     }
```

And in the html, for the `body` tag, add `<body onload="GetRoute();">` so that the function will be called after all the elements are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help. I used your suggestions and the map appears, but without the route, so maybe I did something wrong in the code. I can confiirm that the two requests (txtsource and txtdestination) are passed correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    var source, destination;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
    });

    function GetRoute() 
    {
    source = "<%=Request.form("txtSource")%>"; 
    destination = "<%=Request.form("txtDestination")%>"; 

    if( source != "" && destination != "")
    {
        var rome = new google.maps.LatLng(41.918357, 12.485029);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: rome
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

        //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
        /*source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
        destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;
        */

        var request = {
            origin: source,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });

        //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "<strong>" + "Distanza:" + "</strong>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + distance + "<br />";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "<strong>" + "Durata:" + "</strong>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + duration;

            } else {
                alert("Impossibile trovare la distanza stradale");
            }


        });
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Edit: I have divs in my HTML for the map and the route. That doesn't appear to be the problem, since the map shows, but I have no route on it

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div id="dvMap" style="height: 500px"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="height:500px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;">
<div id="dvPanel" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the html, do you have a `div` with `id="dvPanel"` ?. (BTW, you should edit your post to reflect the changes; no need to add as an answer.)

Comment: indeed I have. BTW sorry, next time I'll edit the main post.

Comment: it is working for me , can you show the html part too ?

Comment: I added the divs in the first post; do you want me to link the actual page? maybe it could help.

Comment: Okay. Move the script to within the head of the document, and it should work